# Managing many-to-many relationship in react-admin

Tags: many-to-many, react-admin

React-admin enterprise edition provides a module called ra-relationships. This gives the ability to deal with many-to-many relationships in the interface. I'm building an app with users and roles as separate resources (i.e. a user can have multiple roles and vice-versa).

From what I can see, the ra-relationships module relies on the premise that your primary keys in all tables (user, roles and user_roles) are simply named "id". However, this particular app has the primary keys as user_id, role_id and user_role_id.

Has anyone come across a method whereas the module can work with this kind of set up?

Comment: you might be able to change the identifers in your dataProvider so readt-admin sees what it expects. Could you post sample code showing what you are doing to make you think  react admin is expecting primary keys called "id"? i dont think react-admin makes any assumptions about your data. My guess is one of your Resources is using a component (like list, create, or show) that has an element with `source="id"`. Try changing this to match the ID in your database

Comment: Thank you for this. I note that react-admin seems to have updated their documentation for this specific module and note that :

"entities expose an identifier called id"

https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-relationships#:~:text=an%20implementation%20detail.-,Out%20of%20scope,%2C%20which%20are%20standard%20components%20in%20react%2Dadmin.,-%3CReferenceManyToManyField%3E